# Bonjour client and server at the same time

Tags: ios, networking, bonjour

Is it possible to setup a bonjour for ios te let the device be a client and server at the same time? I mean i want at the same time(without disconnection) receive and send information to more than one device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can setup a device to be both a Bonjour client and Bonjour server, just make sure you use different services type for Bonjour.  Otherwise it will discover itself.

But if you "want at the same time(without disconnection) receive and send information to more than one device", you don't need to set a device as both server and client Bonjour.  Since  Bonjour is only a network discovery protocols.  One a device discovered or be discovered another devices, and network connections have been established, you can send and receive to/from any connected devices.